# Today() function returns yesterday's date. I think its because of the timezone. How can I correct this?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've encountered a delay in the date that today() returns. I think it has something to do with the timezone but I don't know how to correct it.
For example, I use it today. I live in PH so it must return Oct 21. But it returns Oct 20. How do you I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the spreadsheet's time zone? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515

Answer (score 1):

```
File -> Settings -> Time Zone
```

Change to the location you want.